# How to implement a sticky row in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing a ranking view.

I'd like to highlight and keep the current user's row as an sticky row always visible.

Setting the row as a list header if the user scrolls under the row and as a footer if the user scroll over

How can I do it using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1911

Comment: I need something similar: I'd need the row to be also sticky at the bottom

Comment: then you can customize this library

Comment: I tried to customize the library, since the list decorators are just paint over (or below) the row you can't set click listeners. =(. The alternative is to write a custom LayoutManager but it is a pretty complex

Comment: @Addev, you are right, indeed I am searching help to implement a custom light LayoutManager in my https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter project. However, the project SuperSlim is based on LayoutManager, you can check it, but it is very huge, almost 3400 lines for section and sticky headers only.

Answer (score -3):

You can use help of ViewType.

```
 @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.scheduler_settings_days_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderItems(v);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.scheduler_settings_days_row_header, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderHeader(v);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.scheduler_settings_days_row_footer, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderFooter(v);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    //throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

   @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

 private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you make the highlighted row always visible? Thanks

Comment: @Akbar but it doesn't stick